# Mac does not shutdown properly after update to macOS 13.5

Tags: hardware, ventura, shutdown

Since I updated 16” 2019 MacBookPro (i9) to macOS 13.5, it does not shut down properly.

After a shutdown, the computer simply stays on, for example with the background image.

If the shutdown is initiated from the login screen, it simply falls back to the login screen again.

However, in the recovery mode the computer does shutdown properly; so it must have something to do with the Ventura update.

I already tried reseting the SMC and NVRAM but no luck.

Comment: See if it shuts down properly from safe mode, or from a newly-created 'blank' account.

Comment: "it must be to do with the Ventura update" -- more likely a user process that is getting stuck.

Comment: @benwiggy sice cmd + alt + esc still works in that screen I also thought about that.
Strange enough the issue also happens in the login screen after a cold boot

Comment: @Tetsujin not account related it also happens in the login screen

Comment: In that case, it might be worth running the OS installer again. If you can't find other reports of similar things occurring to other users with 13.5, then it's an isolated case, which could be due to any number of factors. Have you verified the SSD?

Comment: @benwiggy yep i checked disk integrity etc. I'll just run the installer again.
Im afraid there is a process which is not shutdown properly, but I can't find a way to look into running processes when finder etc is already killed. Since im not able to get a shell at that stage

Comment: Use something like Etrecheck to see if you've got any LaunchDaemons that might be causing problems. Have you checked the problem in Safe Boot mode? Does it happen every shutdown, or just some?

Comment: @benwiggy happens on every shutdown, there is a safe boot mode ? how to enter that ?

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh21245/mac It prevents third-party software from launching, and clears some caches.