# Mac show processes which might block shutdown

Tags: macos, ventura, shutdown

Would it be possible to list processes which block a shutdown of the Mac when finder is already killed?

I want to resolve a different issue because I'm suspecting It's caused by a dangling process.

[Mac does not shutdown properly after update to macOS 13.5](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/462757/mac-does-not-shutdown-properly-after-update-to-macos-13-5)

Comment: How do you propose to list these processes when the process that give you an interface (the Finder UI) is killed?  You could try to SSH into the machine, but SSH is likely killed already as well.  Instead of trying to overcome this obstacle, why not focus on the actual issue you suspect you're experiencing.

Comment: @Allan well finder is not the general UI, since the UI of cmd+alt+esc is also still rendered. I figured it should be possible to attach something somewhere, or run a process indefinitely on purpose which is logging all running processes in a file.

Comment: @Allan Overcoming the issues is a nice idea, but I don't even know what the issues is, there must be some process which blocks the shutdown.

Comment: It's not a process that actively blocks a shutdown, it's a process that's can't terminate for some reason that's holding up the rest of the system from shutting down.  Finder *is* the main Interface and the moment you lose all the menus, you lose access to anything that will give you a way back in.  In FreeBSD/Linux, you could access an alternate TTY, but macOS doesn't do this.  Your last option is to SSH in and that's not possible.

Comment: @Allan So its not possible to inject a Process which is terminating after finder ?

Comment: Like I stated in my first comment, *how* are you going to get an interface in which to inject said process?

Comment: @Allan I thought about attaching to the cmd+alt+esc process by replacing its entry command or binary and spinning everything up from there ? I mean since the Taskmanager windows is still somehow operational it should be possible

Comment: That's not a discrete process.  It's a keybinding that's attached the Force Quit which as far as I know isn't a discrete process - it's built into Finder.  You could try attaching another keybinding to Terminal and see if that works.

Comment: @Allan The Force Quit window stays open when you Restart the Finder, so it's independent of the Finder. I'll agree that once processes are quitting at the shutdown stage, it's hard to do anything. I think there used to be "Shutdown Items", but it was removed....

Comment: @benwiggy shutdown items would be the best thing in that case, I would just try to dump all processes with ps aux or something in the shutdown moment. Im really interested I what keeps the machine up. Because I want to know how it got there and what it does, maybe its malicious

Comment: Is it a completely independent process or a child process of Finder?  Either way, the OP is stuck without even a basic interface to do anything, much less access processes.  At a minimum, the OP should kill individual process until the system shuts down (i.e. the first on the list).  If the system shuts down cleanly after that, you know the process hanging things up.

Comment: Exactly, I suspect something went corrupt while updating to Ventura, so the shutdown binary does not initiate a Hardware shutdown anymore, what I don't understand though is why the wallpaper stays. In Logged in mode as well as in the login mask the wallpaper stay in place when the Mac reaches that state